# База данных + Hibernate

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, hibernate

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой незнания Hibernate.
В общем у меня есть две таблицы с зависимыми столбцами. 
К примеру есть таблица автосервис:

> id | название | картинка

Во второй таблице хранятся данные об услугах, к примеру:

> id | шиномонтаж | замена колеса | 200 | id сервиса

Вопросы:

- Как мне с помощью аннотаций `Hibernate` сделать зависимости между столбцами ?
- Как мне получить объект сервиса, в котором будет храниться список
  объектов услуг для этого сервиса ?

К примеру, как сделать архитектуру такой, чтобы при обращению к `repository.findAll()` я смог получить объект `AutoService` с полем `List<>` услуг ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AutoRate")
public class AutoService {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "imageURL", nullable = false)
    private String imageURL;

    @Column(name = "mapCoordinate", nullable = false)
    private String mapCoordinate;

    @Column(name = "websiteURL", nullable = false)
    private String websiteURL;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    public AutoService() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public String getMapCoordinate() {
        return mapCoordinate;
    }

    public String getWebsiteURL() {
        return websiteURL;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

И класс услуги для сервиса:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Service")
public class Service {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "serviceName", nullable = false)
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "autoServiceId", nullable = false)
    private long serviceId;

    public Service() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот вопрос относится к Hibernate, а не Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в класс `AutoService` следующее поле:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "serviceId")
List<Service> services;
```